# Add a different picture for every section with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm wondering if there is a way in LaTex to add a different picture to every Section header using `fancyhdr`, but without defining `\fancypagestyle` XX times.

I think a good starting point could be giving a Section and its corresponding picture the same name, but then -- how to define `\fancypagestyle` using a variable/placeholder? (Sorry, I still don't have a working piece of code).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to add the image to the header? Will there be something else in the header? Please clarify.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you have tried:. The document you want to use is probably relevant and it would be good to see what layout you want, otherwise people might waste time doing something else. Why don't you paste a `\fancypagestyle` that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an additional optional argument for `\section` to pass in the filename for an associated picture like `\section(<image file>)[<toc name>]{<full name>}`. Assuming that this additional information gets stored in a macro called `\headerpic` it is possible to simply declare the header once like so:

```
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\headerpic}}
```

A possible implementation would look like this.

```
\let\ltx@section\section
\def\section{\kernel@ifnextchar(%
  {\@section@HP}%
  {\@section@HP(\@headerpic@default)}%
}
\def\@section@HP(#1){%
  \clearpage\xdef\headerpic{#1}\ltx@section
}
```

Passing in no image will result in falling back to `\@headerpic@default`, which should be set manually or through a wrapper to make it nice looking:

```
\def\SetHeaderpicDefault#1{%
  \xdef\headerpic{#1}
  \xdef\@headerpic@default{#1}
}
```

This also initializes `\headerpic` which is crucial if the first header is typeset without a section being present.

[image: output0]

[image: output1]

### Complete Code

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% This is just to make sure that the the demo pictures used are present
\write18{wget https://i.picsum.photos/id/388/2000/200.jpg}
\write18{wget https://i.picsum.photos/id/495/2000/200.jpg}
\write18{wget https://i.picsum.photos/id/520/2000/200.jpg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\headerpic}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@section\section
\def\section{\kernel@ifnextchar(%
  {\@section@HP}%
  {\@section@HP(\@headerpic@default)}%
}
\def\@section@HP(#1){%
  \clearpage\xdef\headerpic{#1}\ltx@section
}
\def\SetHeaderpicDefault#1{%
  \xdef\headerpic{#1}
  \xdef\@headerpic@default{#1}
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{40pt}
\SetHeaderpicDefault{388-2000x200.jpg}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum
\section(495-2000x200.jpg){Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum
\section(520-2000x200.jpg){Dolor Sit}
\lipsum
\section{Dolor Sit}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

A major caveat, however, is that the `\@section@HP` macro enforces a new page to make sure the right picture is associated with the according section.

If you want to avoid the syntactic sugar of above soultion, one could of course go with something like

```
\section[<toc name>]{<full name>}
\SetHeaderpic{<file name>}
```

with `\def\SetHeaderpic#1{\xdef\headerpic{#1}}`.